# What is the logstash grok pattern for apache error..?

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I'm trying to configure a logstash filter for an apache log errors filter definition. It is basically the 'combined' LogFormat with some additional field, here is the apache log format definition:

> [11446] [Thu Jan 30 07:50:49 2020] [debug]: RT::Date used
>   Time::ParseDate to make '2020-01-31T07:20:46Z' 1580446800
>   (/app/rt4/sbin/../lib/RT/Date.pm:274)

or it could be of this format:

> [Wed Jun 26 22:13:22 2013] [error] [client 10.10.10.100] PHP Fatal
>   error:  Uncaught exception '\Foo\Bar'

I tried the below solution:

> APACHE_ERROR_TIME %{DAY} %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %{YEAR}
>   APACHE_ERROR_LOG [%{APACHE_ERROR_TIME:timestamp}]
>   [%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}] (?:[client %{IPORHOST:clientip}]
>   ){0,1}%{GREEDYDATA:errormsg}

but it gives a **grok_match_failure**.

Please help me with a **generic working pattern** for the above string (meaning it should not matter even if one of the part of string is not there)

**Updated Question:**

So, the above worked with https://stackoverflow.com/a/59986583/4127230 and I have again got stuck with another system log string.

Can you also suggest a generic grok pattern same for the below strings:

> Feb  2 18:21:14 localhost prometheus_postgres_exporter: time=\"2020-02-02T18:21:14+04:00\" level=info msg=\"Error while closing non-pinging DB connection: \" source=\"postgres_exporter.go:1001\"

and

> Feb  2 05:56:10 localhost logstash: [2020-02-02T05:56:10,934][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>6}

Comment: Why not use 2 different match cases for the same grok filter?

Comment: First you need to escape the brackets like this: `\[\]`

Answer (score 0):

Using the provided `APACHE_ERROR_TIME`, I got a match with this pattern:

```
\[%{APACHE_ERROR_TIME:timestamp}\] \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\](?: \[client %{IPORHOST:clientip}\] ){0,1}%{GREEDYDATA:errormsg}
```

In addition to escaping the square brackets, there was some misplaced spaces that prevented the match.

For:

```
[11446] [Thu Jan 30 07:50:49 2020] [debug]: RT::Date used Time::ParseDate to make '2020-01-31T07:20:46Z' 1580446800 (/app/rt4/sbin/../lib/RT/Date.pm:274)
```

Result:

```
timestamp   Thu Jan 30 07:50:49 2020
loglevel    debug
clientip    
errormsg    : RT::Date used Time::ParseDate to make '2020-01-31T07:20:46Z' 1580446800 (/app/rt4/sbin/../lib/RT/Date.pm:274)
before match:   [11446]
```

For:

```
[Wed Jun 26 22:13:22 2013] [error] [client 10.10.10.100] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception '\Foo\Bar'
```

Result:

```
timestamp   Wed Jun 26 22:13:22 2013
loglevel    error
clientip    10.10.10.100
errormsg    PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception '\Foo\Bar'
```

Comment: Can you please try your grok expression here https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ and then share the results..?

Comment: Thanks, I got it working with a small tweak. Can you suggest a grok pattern for system log updated in the answer.

Comment: Before I start to work on them, could you tell me what parts of the log you're interested in extracting?

Comment: Thanks, but I got the solution for the updated one as well.